# Fourier transform through graph

Tags: calculus, power-series, fourier-transform

I have to find the Fourier transform of this function:
[image]

I wrote that :
$x(t) = \sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty}\sin(\frac{2\pi k}{3})\delta(t-k)$ where $k \in Z$

It looks like a convolution but the $t$ should be $\in Z$
Can I do this (?)
$X(\omega) = $
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty}\sin(\frac{2\pi k}{3})\delta(t-k)e^{j\omega t}dt$   $=\sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(\frac{2\pi k}{3})\delta(t-k)e^{j\omega t}dt = \sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty}sin(\frac{2\pi k}{3})\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{j\omega t}\delta(t-k)dt$
And the Fourier tranform of :  $\delta(t-k) \rightarrow e^{j\omega k}$
\
So : $X(\omega) = \sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty}\sin(\frac{2\pi k}{3})e^{j\omega k}$
And : $\sin(\frac{2\pi k}{3}) =\frac{1}{2j}(e^{j\frac{2\pi k}{3}}  - e^{-j\frac{2\pi k}{3}})$
$X(\omega) = \sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}( e^{k(j\frac{2\pi}{3} + j\omega)}  - e^{k(-j\frac{2\pi k}{3}+ j\omega)})$  but how do I proceeed?

**update****
I thought another way :
this signal is periodic so I may can express it with fourier - analysis :
$ c_n = \begin{cases} 
      \delta(t-n) & n = 3k + 1 \\
      -\delta(t-n) & n = 3k +2 \\
      0 & n = 3k + 3 
   \end{cases}$ where $k \in Z$
Then we can express $x(t)$ as :
$x(t) = \begin{cases} 
      \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-n)& n =3k+1 \\
       \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}-\delta(t-n)& n=3k+2 \\
      0 & n = 3k + 3
   \end{cases} \rightarrow  x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT -1)  -\delta(t-nT -2)$
In my table with fourier transforms (provided by my uni) there this property:
$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT) \leftrightarrow \frac{2\pi}{T}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\omega - n\omega_0)$
$\\ \\$

So :
$X(\omega) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-j\omega}\delta(\omega -\omega_0)-e^{-j\omega 2}\delta(\omega -\omega_0) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-j\omega}\delta(\omega -\omega_0)e^{-j\omega}(1 - e^{-j\omega}) $
And $e^{-j\omega}(1 - e^{-j\omega}) = e^{-j\omega}e^{\frac{-j\omega}{2}}(e^{\frac{j\omega}{2}} - e^{\frac{-j\omega}{2}} ) = e^{\frac{-3j\omega}{2}}(2jsin(\frac{\omega}{2}))$
And
$X(\omega) =  
     \frac{2\pi}{T} e^{\frac{-3j\omega}{2}}(2jsin(\frac{\omega}{2}))\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\omega -\omega_0)
$

Comment: Take care: $\sin(\frac{2\pi k}{3}) =\frac{1}{2 \color{red}{j}}(e^{j\frac{2\pi k}{3}}  - e^{-j\frac{2\pi k}{3}})$

Comment: Different things . 0) I don't understand how you can obtain $X(\omega) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-j\omega}\delta(\omega -\omega_0) ...$1) what is the value of $\omega_0$ ? 2) in the last expression, you should not keep $sin(\omega/2)$ but distribute it on the $\delta$ inside the $\sum$ in order to apply the rule I have given $f(\omega)\delta(\omega-a)= f(a)\delta(\omega-a)$, 3) A typo:There should be an $n \omega_0$" present inside your last expressions with $\delta(...)$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, due to the rule $f(x)\delta(x-a)=f(a)\delta(x-a)$:

$$x(t) = \sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty}\sin(\frac{2\pi k}{3})\delta(t-k)= \sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty}\sin(\frac{2\pi t}{3})\delta(t-k)$$

Hereafter, I advise you to use the formalism of [Dirac comb(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb):

$$x(t)=\sin(\frac{2\pi t}{3})\underbrace{\sum_{k= -\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-k)}_{\text{unit Dirac comb }\text{Ш}}\tag{1}$$

where, more generally:

$$\displaystyle \operatorname {\text{Ш}} _{T}(t)\ \triangleq \ \sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty }\delta (t-kT)={\frac {1}{T}}\operatorname {\text{Ш}} \left({\frac {t}{T}}\right)$$

with the property that:

$$\displaystyle \operatorname {\text{Ш}} _{T}(t){ \ \ \stackrel {\mathcal {F}} {\longleftrightarrow }} \ \ {\frac {\sqrt {2\pi }}{T}}\operatorname {\text{Ш}} _{\frac {2\pi }{T}}(\omega ) \ \ \text{or } \ {\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi }}}\sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-i\omega nT}\tag{2}$$

(the last expression making the link with Fourier **series**, but we haven't to use it here).

Therefore, using (2), the Fourier Transform of product (1) is convolution product

$$(\mathcal{F}x)(\omega)=-i \pi (\delta(\omega-\frac{2\pi}{3})-\delta(\omega+\frac{2\pi}{3})) \color{red}{\star} 
 \sqrt {2\pi } \sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty }\delta (\omega-2 \pi k)$$

It remains to take all the convolution products, an easy task using the shifting property of delta distribution:

$$\delta(\omega-a) \star \delta(\omega-b)=\delta(\omega-(a+b)).$$

**Remark 1:** Formula (2) is rather natural: a Dirac comb with quite spaced "teeth" will be transformed into a Dirac comb with quite clenched "teeth".

**Remark 2:** I see in your computation that you come back to the definition of Fourier Transform (as an integral). Why not, but in virtually all practical cases, we only need tables and formulas.

Comment: I just added for clarity a first transformation right at the beginning. Any comment ?

Comment: thank you for you answer, I am still trying to figure out how to normalise it, I have $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-k)$ in order to gain $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-kT)$ since $T=3$ this is going to result to a singal with non-zero values only in multiples of 3 $t=3,6,9,...3k,...$ but this does not represent the graph , right?

Comment: Do you mean that in your figure, it is not $-1,0,1,2...$ the one must read on the abscissas' axis but $-3,0,3,6,...$ ?

Comment: i mean .. I haven't yet understood how can I tranform this given graph in a represantion that takes non- zero values only in -3, 0, 3, 6 ,... when the given graph has a signal that takes non zero values in -1, 0, 1, 2 ( if i am not clear is there another way to communicate?)

Comment: I added a new answer if you want to provide feedback